# Create a line chart using D3 with data from an array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a D3 line chart using data from an array. I am getting the data from the database but I can't seem to get the path lines to populate. I don't get any errors in the console so I'm a little confused on what I'm doing wrong. I'm still new to D3.

Here is my code:

```
        //set dimensions
        var margin = {top:30, right:20, bottom:30, left:50},
            width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        //parse date/time 
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%b-%d").parse;

        //set ranges
        var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

        //define axes
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
            .orient("bottom").ticks(10);
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
            .orient("left").ticks(10);

        //define the line
        var volumesLine = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) {return x(parseDate(d.MonthStartDate));})
            .y(function(d) {return y(d.Volumes);});

        //get data from database
        var data = {MonthStartDate: [errorData[1]["MonthStartDate"]], Volumes: [errorData[1]["Volume"]], VolumeId: [errorData[1]["VolumeId"]]};
        console.log(data);

        //nest data by volume id
        data = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d){ return d.VolumeId; })
            .entries(data);

        data.forEach(function(d) {
            svg.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", volumesLine(d.values));
        });

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ return d.MonthStartDate; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.Volumes; })]);

        //add the svg to canvas
        var svg = d3.select("#volumeChart")
            //.datum(data)
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");            

        //add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        //add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);

        //create path
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", volumesLine);
```

Comment: This might be helpful http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/d8be922a10cb0b148cd5

Comment: I have looked at that and got a lot of help from it, but still can't seem to get the path lines to draw

Comment: Do you have a data sample that you can share?

Comment: I don't, but it's just in a database table with the MonthStartDate, Volumes, and VolumesId. If that helps at all